# NGX-Datatable some number values displaying as 'Infinity'

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am trying to figure out why I am seeing the word 'Infinity' displayed for some values I have coming in for my table.

For example, I have a column named 'Bill To' with a value '20E7543' as a string.  I see in the console log that the data is coming from our API correctly, `'Bill To': '20E7543'`.  But whenever the table loads I end up seeing this:

[image: bill_toAngular*]

This is only happening to any column with a value that includes an 'E', all other values that do not have an 'E' in these columns are unaffected and show up fine.  I believe my code is ok since the data is coming in correctly, so I am led to believe that this must be a feature in ngx-datatable.

**My question is:** Is there a way to override this so I can show the data correctly?

Angular Version: 8.0

NGX-Datatable Version: 16.1.1 (@swimlane/ngx-datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was on my side and did not have to do with ngx-datatable.  It had to do with how we are parsing our row data using JSON.parse.